# Doesn't Paarfi's description of Mario's defeat of the Orb constitute treason?

Tags: history, steven-brust, dragaera

In Five Hundred Years After, Paarfi describes in some detail the means by which Mario Greymist manages to disable the Orb long enough to kill the Emperor. Since, in-universe, FHYA is also a book available on Dragaera, this seems like it would amount to treason. At the very least, there should be an investigation as to who leaked him this "classified" information (which would be Sethra, presumably).

Is this an instance (like the discrepancies between his and Aliera's accounts of Adron's actions leading up to the Disaster) where we simply can't take Paarfi's "history" as accurate? Is there any secondary evidence for determining whether he's been misinformed or is just making something up that sounds good?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in some places names are redacted.

I would like to think that the version which we are reading is the original, as submitted to the University, while the version published in-universe and widely available is further edited/redacted.

It wasn't so long ago that a young physics PhD created instructions to make an atomic bomb as his doctoral thesis --- when finished, the department secretary congratulated him, told him it had received an "A", and that the thesis was classified top secret and all copies were being sent to Los Alamos for safekeeping --- I'd think the Special Tasks Group could manage something like to that in-universe.

Comment: I've heard that story. But is it true?

Comment: I read it in _Reader's Digest_ before the internet --- here: https://www.villagevoice.com/2003/12/16/the-a-bomb-kid/