# What sword or swords does Vlad have in the "Special Tasks" part of Tiassa?

Tags: vlad-taltos, dragaera

The third part of *Tiassa* is written by the incomparable, masterful, and, of course, completely modest Paarfi of Roundwood.

When Vlad is recovering in the guardhouse, Lady Saruchka brings him the sword that he lost while fending off attackers and then taking a somewhat unplanned swim. However, at this point in the timeline, Vlad has *two* swords: his normal fencing sword, and his 'great' sword.

> i.e. the Great Weapon Godslayer, or, as Vlad prefers to call her, Lady Teldra.

The [Lyorn Records wiki entry for Sara](http://dragaera.wikia.com/wiki/Sara) currently claims that the sword she returned to him was not his normal sword, but I see no evidence in the text for this. If it weren't his normal sword, the Phoenix Guards would likely have commented on the psychic impressions of it as it drew near. However, if it were his normal sword, I would have thought that the Phoenix Guards, particularly Lord Khaavren, would have made comment about the other sword in Vlad's personal effects.

Khaavren definitely would have commented had he pulled anything other than his normal sword in the bar fight at the end, and, no matter how obnoxious she thought her family was being, I don't see Lady Sara countenancing the side-effects of Vlad using the other sword on members of her family. In the bar fight scene, Paarfi makes mention of Vlad's different fighting style and the type of sword he has, which we recognize as the Eastern fencing style with what looks like his normal sword.

Owing to Vlad's special connection to his other sword, I can't see him leaving it behind, however it doesn't appear to appear in this story. It's also clear that, despite Paarfi's own claims to accuracy, Paarfi rather embellishes these little histories of his and is not a primary source. He might very well not have known of Vlad's two swords, and so not included them in his story. He might also have not mentioned Vlad's second sword for reasons of his own.

All that said, it might be that there's something to read between the lines that I have missed. It's also possible that Paarfi is simply inaccurate, that the details of his second sword did not make it into the official report, or even that Paarfi is leaving it out for reasons of his own. It's even possible that Vlad has secreted one of his swords elsewhere for the duration of this story. What sword or swords does Vlad have in reality during this story? He certainly has both in the Vlad-narrated afterward that occurs shortly after these events.

Related: [Doesn't Paarfi's description of Mario's defeat of the Orb constitute treason?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35698/75596)